# Navigation Drawer not responding to clicks

Tags: android, webview, navigation-drawer

I am trying to build an app for Android which has Navigation drawer. By some older tutorials and questions here I figured out how to do some of it. But now it is not reacting to clicks.

```
package ********************;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true); 

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                getWindow().setTitle(title); 
            }
        });

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
        web.loadUrl("http://***************************");



        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("HOME", R.mipmap.arrow));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("FEEDBACK", R.mipmap.arrow));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("ABOUT", R.mipmap.arrow));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setClickable(true);


        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("CLICK",String.valueOf(position));
                //Replace fragment content
                //updateFragment();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My goal is to open other url with WebView, but now I am just using Log.d to catch any clicks.

Comment: @Raghunandan I did: https://paste.ofcode.org/ANS5N5VsepALJ4jkLMrUj3

Comment: still does not work??. Not sure..

Comment: @Raghunandan no. Fragment layout one xml https://paste.ofcode.org/U7xUrRvqcqQQXr8aDwGi5q

Comment: I tried a sample with the code it works. Do you not see the log at `Log.d("CLICK",String.valueOf(position));` and also its better you switch to navigationview

Comment: @Raghunandan I do not see the log in LOGCAT. When I place the same Log.d on other place (changing String.valueOf(position) to "helloooo") the log works.

Comment: can you show your `activity_main.xml`. It should work. i see nothing wrong with the code you posted

Comment: @Raghunandan here it is https://paste.ofcode.org/b7NjHQP9dfgRnbw7WdzEJC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your pastebin change your activity_main.xml to

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

There is no need for a `FrameLayout` as your content is just a `WebView`

Comment: @OndrejVrabel but you should switch to navigationview.

Comment: OK, I will consider it in next versions.